# How can I filter JSON column in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Lets say that we have simple table,

- id - user id
- rooms - number of rooms which the user is searching in JSON type.

```
id rooms
1 ["3.0","4.0"]
2 ["3.0"]
3 ["1.0"]
```

How can I filter for example user id which is searching 3 rooms?

I know that code like:

```sql
SELECT
    id
FROM 
    example_column
WHERE
rooms::text LIKE '%3.0%'
```

is working, but i'm lookig for more gentle method.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the "exists" `?` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to test for elements in an array:

```
SELECT id
FROM the_table
WHERE rooms ? '3.0';
```

The operator is only available for `jsonb` values, if you are really using a `json` column, you need to cast it:

```
WHERE rooms::jsonb ? '3.0';
```